# Not able to use conditional tags in for loop in Django template file

Tags: python, django-templates, jinja2

I'm using Django 1.4/python 2.7.9 (because I'm required to, I know 1.4 is pretty old now) and I'm pretty green with django/python.  In my template file, I seem to be unable to use any of the cool conditional tags like ifchanged or ifequal within a for loop.

For example:

```
{% for asample in allsamples %}
    {% ifchanged asample.brand %}
        <h2>{{ asample.brand }}</h2>
    {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```

This throws the error "Encountered unknown tag 'ifchanged'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'."

I've tried ifequals in there too - same error.  Is there something preventing me from using other tags within the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about `jinja2` solution, you can workaround it with `if/else` and `set`:

```
{% for asample in allsamples %}
    {% if asample.brand != last_brand %}
        <h2>{{ asample.brand }}</h2>
        {% set last_brand = asample.brand %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, as I said, I'm pretty green and working in a legacy app.  So, the premise here is that I am not actually using the Django template engine, but instead Jinja?

Comment: @Todd correct, and this is pretty much ok and probably the template rendering speed was the reason - though it is not recommended to replace base django components. I've worked with a similar setup when the django template engine was replaced by jinja2 (with the help of `coffin` module).

Answer (score 0):

I was using Jinja 3.1.2, and I found this [solution](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for):

```
{% for asample in allsamples %}
    {% if loop.changed(asample.brand) %}
        <h2>{{ asample.brand }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```